# How can we increase site traffic?

Tags: discussion, participation

The biggest problem for this beta is that we have very little outside traffic. This site has been an important resource for me as a Ukrainian learner, but there are not many of my kind. How can we reach the community of native speakers?

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that there is already a solid community of *native* speakers here. What we really need is *attracting two other categories of people*:

1. language learners — non-native speakers who study Slavonic languages in general and the Ukrainian in particular;
2. Ukrainian nationals who (like myself) at a certain moment decided to switch to Ukrainian in family and on public.

While I expect that the latter category would be bigger by number, I sincerely think that **questions in English can become a powerful driving force** that generates the interest. The reason is simple: there are various Russian/Ukrainian-speaking forums/boards about the Ukrainian language, but there is nearly none for questions in English. So an average person can find more or less the answer to their question elsewhere, while there are not that many such places for English speakers.

According to Analytics, people come from two sources:

1. Social networks (primarily, Facebook);
2. Search engines (primarily, Google);

**Social networks** are straightforward: your friends learn about your interests, find out what you're doing, and may become interested, too.

To make hits from the **search engines**, there must be already questions on the site, indexed. Only then someone comes to Google, asks **до побачення write together or separate**, gets a high-rank link to our **pre-existing question**, clicks, reads an answer, and goes away (90%). Only several percent of people start navigating around, creating an account, etc. But in order to get "real" users, there must be a ten (or hundred?) times more anonymous visitors.

---

Now, having the goal and the reasoning, we can tell what to do:

1. **Ask and Answer** in English; **Google will never index a non-existing question!** :-)
2. **Share** to blogs, social networks, and wherever you may expect to find those who would be interested, too;
3. **Vote** to reward the existing posts;

Comment: I strongly disagree with "there is already a solid community of native speakers here" and that now we need to attract other kinds of visitors. While I appreciate existing members of community and some of them are really high-educated — still our community contains much smaller number of native speakers than it could contain. Therefore we really need to attract all kinds of visitors, including (but not limited to) native speakers.

Comment: @Sasha, my vision is that we have enough people to answer questions, while not that many who **ask**. As soon as a question is asked, it often gets answer *within two or three hours*. Does it make sense?

Comment: My vision is the opposite. I have several dozens of questions I'd like to ask, but I don't ask them, because… because I see not so many actively answering people and I'm afraid to overload them. I.e. +20 for 200 answerers isn't too large load, but for 10 answerers it is. I.e. IMHO our answering community isn't large enough (though some of its members are really competent). Asking is always easier than answering.

Comment: Perhaps encouraging existing users to edit questions to add English translations could catch the attention of English-language users.