# "Імпульс" березня 2018 року

Tags: discussion, participation, site-promotion

Аналіз [даних](http://data.stackexchange.com/ukrainian/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=240#graph) активності [Ukrainian Language StackExchange](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/) показав суттєвий поштовх в діяльності в березні 2018 року. Хто знає, чим він спричинений, поділіться будь ласка.

[image: Графік активності Ukrainian Language StackExchange з лютого 2017 року до червня 2018]

Можливо є сенс "реплікувати" цю подію, щоб нарощувати базу користувачів, питань, відповідей та голосів? Бо питання більше ніж актуальні:

- [How can we encourage users' participation on this site?](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/235/260)
- [Залучення нових користувачів](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/173/260)
- [How can we increase site traffic?](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/185/260)
- [Як має виглядати наш промо-лист на катедри мовознавства (й до інших схожих інституцій)?](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/227/260)
- [З'явився бот, що експортує запитання/відповіді з UkrSE до Facebook](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205/260)

Answer (score 3):

На початку березня 2018 на сайті зареєструвалася група користувачів — переважно студентів та викладачів університетів Львова — які проявили активність, за що їм наша подяка.

Наскільки мені відомо, ніякої рекламної кампанії не проводилося. Припускаю, що просто хтось з них дізнався про цей сайт, зареєструвався, зацікавився і запросив друзів і колег. Тому, напевне, ми не в змозі самостійно реплікувати саме цю подію.

Але є цілком типові рішення, про які писалося у відповідях на запитання, на які ви самі надали посилання:

- **Створюйте** дописи. Більшість користувачів приходять з пошукових сайтів. Ґуґл ніколи не проіндексує запитання, якого ніколи не існувало;
- **Поширюйте** у соцмережах: кнопка `share` під дописом включає ваш власний ідентифікатор, за поширення дають [беджики](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/badges) Announcer, Booster, Publicist (у секції Other Badges);
- **Голосуйте**, щоб вже наявні якісні дописи отримували подяку і стимулювали їхніх авторів дописувати ще;
- Я давно думав робити серію **промо-роликів** на зразок [оцього](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/a/560/60), але поки що не маю співавторів, а самому — нудно;
- Беріть участь у **модерації**. Гарно облаштований сайт приваблює більшу кількість новачків, яким стає цікаво.
  Моє глибоке переконання, що більшість модераторських функцій доступні простим користувачам: **голосування, флаги, [reviews](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review), редагування дописів, [редагування теґів](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/tags), участь у Meta** тощо.
  Ваша активність сьогодні — це ваше призначення/обрання модератором узавтра.

---

P.S. Статистика усіх сайтів мережі Stack Exchange у квітні 2018 [зазнала пошкоджень](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/187133) і може не відповідати дійсності. Майте це на увазі, коли аналізуєте інформацію про відвідування.

Comment: Статистика з data.stackexchange.com базується на "діях", інформація про які не була втрачена, пошкодження про які Ви згадуєте стосується відвідуваності, що в статистику data.stackexchange.com не входить (принаймні по тих графіках, що я згадував).

Comment: Наскільки достовірною є інформацію про "зареєструвалася група користувачів — студентів та викладачів університетів Львова"? Чи можете підказати спосіб, яким можна визначити діапазон ідентифікаторів тих користувачів?

Якщо канал через "освітян/науковців" запрацював один раз, то чим варіант, що згадується в https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/227/260 "не варіант", може запрацює "ще раз"?

Comment: @myroslav, промо-лист, на який ви посилаєтеся, застряг у стадії обговорення змісту. Він ніколи не був надісланий, наскільки мені відомо. Але ви можете долучитися до створення тексту і розсилки.